# Calculate Recency based on specific conditions across more than one columns - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

df:

```
ID     Limit    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_180_365
1      500      60       15          30            1
2      300      0        15          5             10
3      800      0        0           10            6
4      100      0        0           0             370
5      600      0        6           5             10
6      800      0        0           15            6
7      500      10       10          30            9
8      200      0        0           0             0
```

About the data

```
ID - customer ID
Limit - Limit
N_30 - Number of transaction in last 30 days
N_31_90 - Number of transaction in last 31 to 90 days.
N_91_180 - Number of transaction in last 91 to 180 days.
N_180_365 - Number of transaction in last 281 to 365 days.
```

From the above df I would like to extract a column called `Recency`.

Explanation:

```
if df['N_30'] != 0, then Recency = (30/df['N_30'])
elif df['N_31_90'] != 0 then Recency = 30 + (60/df['N_31_90'])
elif df['N_91_180'] != 0 then Recency = 90 + (90/df['N_91_180'])
elif df['N_181_365'] != 0 then Recency = 180 + (185/df['N_181_365'])
else Recency = 730
```

Expected output:

```
ID     Limit    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_180_365    Recency
1      500      60       15          30            1            (30/60) = 0.5
2      300      0        15          5             10           30+(60/15) = 34
3      800      0        0           10            6            90+90/10 = 100
4      100      0        0           0             370          180+(185/370) = 180.5           
5      600      0        6           5             10           30+(60/6) = 36
6      800      0        0           15            6            90+(90/15) = 96
7      500      10       10          30            9            30/10 = 3
8      200      0        0           0             0            730
```

Comment: Your sample input and output are different as well as your sample calculation of `Recency`. Can you correct the differences? (e.g. N_91_180 for third row is 15 vs 10, and 90 + (90/10) is 99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, using boolean masking with `bfill`:

```
pd.set_option("use_inf_as_na", True)
df2 = df.filter(like="N_")
df["Recency"] = (df2.eq(0) * [30, 60, 90, 180]).sum(1) + ([30, 60, 90, 185] / df2).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Limit  N_30  N_31_90  N_91_180  N_180_365  Recency
0   1    500    60       15        30          1      0.5
1   2    300     0       15         5         10     34.0
2   3    800     0        0        10          6     99.0
3   4    100     0        0         0        370    180.5
4   5    600     0        6         5         10     40.0
5   6    800     0        0        15          6     96.0
6   7    500    10       10        30          9      3.0
```

Comment: if all zero it should be 730

Comment: In case of all zeros, it will be NaN, so you can `df["Recency"].fillna(730)` as a last step ;)

Comment: added a similar question kindly look into it at your convenience.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582211/derive-a-feature-or-column-based-on-the-given-condition-in-pandas