# Derive a feature or column based on the given condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df as shown below

```
ID     Age_days    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_180_365
1      201         60       15          30            1
2      800         0        15          5             10
3      800         0        0           10            6
4      100         0        0           0             370
5      600         0        6           5             10
6      800         0        0           15            6
7      500         10       10          30            9
8      200         0        0           0             0
9      500         0        0           0             0
```

From the above `df` I would like to derive a column called `Recency`

Explanation:

```
if df['N_30'] != 0, then Recency = (30/df['N_30'])
elif df['N_31_90'] != 0 then Recency = 30 + (60/df['N_31_90'])
elif df['N_91_180'] != 0 then Recency = 90 + (90/df['N_91_180'])
elif df['N_181_365'] != 0 then Recency = 180 + (185/df['N_181_365'])
else 
  if df['age_days'] <= 365, Recency = df['age_days']
  else Recency = 366
```

Expected output:

```
ID     Limit    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_180_365    Recency
1      201      60       15          30            1            (30/60) = 0.5
2      800      0        15          5             10           30+(60/15) = 34
3      800      0        0           10            6            90+90/10 = 100
4      100      0        0           0             370          180+(185/370) = 180.5           
5      600      0        6           5             10           30+(60/6) = 36
6      800      0        0           15            6            90+(90/15) = 96
7      500      10       10          30            9            30/10 = 3
8      200      0        0           0             0            200
9      500      0        0           0             0            366
```

I tried below code

```
pd.set_option("use_inf_as_na", True)
df2 = df[['N_30', 'N_31_90', 'N_91_180', 'N_180_365']]
df["Recency"] = (df2.eq(0) * [30, 60, 90, 180]).sum(1) + ([30, 60, 90, 185] / df2).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]
df["Recency"].fillna(366)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['N_30'] != 0, df['N_31_90'] != 0, df['N_91_180'] != 0, df['N_180_365'] != 0, df['Age_days'] <= 365]

choices = [(30/df['N_30']), 30 + (60/df['N_31_90']), 90 + (90/df['N_91_180']), 180 + (185/df['N_180_365']), df['Age_days']]

df['Recency']=np.select(conditions, choices, default=366)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Age_days  N_30  N_31_90  N_91_180  N_180_365  Recency
0   1       201    60       15        30          1      0.5
1   2       800     0       15         5         10     34.0
2   3       800     0        0        10          6     99.0
3   4       100     0        0         0        370    180.5
4   5       600     0        6         5         10     40.0
5   6       800     0        0        15          6     96.0
6   7       500    10       10        30          9      3.0
7   8       200     0        0         0          0    200.0
8   9       500     0        0         0          0    366.0
```

I'm assuming few correction, I'm using `N_180_365` instead of `N_181_365` which you have in condition but not in DF.

Comment: can you pls share your output

Answer (score 2):

Just for learning purpose.

you can try out creeating dict and mapping the elements.

```
def func(x):
    if (x[x['coln']]!=0):
#     if x!=np.nan:
        return (d[x['coln']](x[x['coln']]))
    elif x['Age_days']<=365:
        return x['Age_days'] 
    else:
        return 366

d = {'N_30': lambda x: (30/x), 'N_31_90': lambda x: 30 + (60/x), 'N_91_180': lambda x: 90 + (90/x), 
'N_180_365': lambda x: 180 + (185/x)}

df['recency'] = df.assign(coln = df.filter(like='N').idxmax(axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)).apply(func,axis=1)
```

**df:**

|  | ID | Age_days | N_30 | N_31_90 | N_91_180 | N_180_365 | recency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 201 | 60 | 15 | 30 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 800 | 0 | 15 | 5 | 10 | 34.0 |
| 2 | 3 | 800 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 6 | 99.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 370 | 180.5 |
| 4 | 5 | 600 | 0 | 6 | 5 | 10 | 198.5 |
| 5 | 6 | 800 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 6 | 96.0 |
| 6 | 7 | 500 | 10 | 10 | 30 | 9 | 93.0 |
| 7 | 8 | 200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 200.0 |
| 8 | 9 | 500 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 366.0 |

### Correction:

It should be:

```
 df.filter(like='N').replace(0,np.nan).notna().idxmax(axis=1)
```

After correction you will get the same result.