# Apply lambda to change a column based on the length of the column value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am very new to pandas and I want to know how easily with lambda can we apply the below sql logic to a pandas column .

```
case 
when length( EXTERNAL_REFERENCE ) <= 7 then EXTERNAL_REFERENCE  
when length( EXTERNAL_REFERENCE ) <= 8 then substring( EXTERNAL_REFERENCE , 2 , 7 )   
else substring( EXTERNAL_REFERENCE , 3 , 8 ) end  ) as EXTERNAL_REFERENCE
```

Where external reference is the pandas column I need to apply this logic to . Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `np.where` or `np.select` will help. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582211/derive-a-feature-or-column-based-on-the-given-condition-in-pandas/66582851#66582851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the syntax, but you need something like this,

```
 def custom_external_reference(EXTERNAL_REFERENCE):
      if EXTERNAL_REFERENCE.str.len() <= 7:
          return EXTERNAL_REFERENCE
      elif EXTERNAL_REFERENCE.str.len() <= 8:
          return EXTERNAL_REFERENCE.str[2:7]
      else:
          return EXTERNAL_REFERENCE.str[3:8]


 df['EXTERNAL_REFERENCE'] = df['EXTERNAL_REFERENCE'].apply(custom_external_reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically state lambda, I'm guessing you want it in a single call. That probably goes against good readability practices, so I'd suggest something like @Always Sunny's answer. But I'll offer this as an alternative. And I wanted to learn about where anyway. Not quite a single call, but it does save making another function if you're opposed to that.

If you really want to do something like this, you can, and it's not too bad with a few line breaks.

```
results['external_reference'] = results['external_reference'].where(
    results['external_reference'].str.len() > 8,
    results['external_reference'].str[2:7],
    axis=0
).where(
    results['external_reference'].str.len() == 8,
    results['external_reference'].str[1:6],
    axis=0
)
```